# Perl - File deletion not happening

Tags: perl, rename, unlink

I have a file in which I have to add 2 lines.
For that I open the file, read the lines, add new lines and save the file as a new temp file. Now I want to delete the original file and rename the new file to original file name. But somehow it is not happening.

```
unlink $file;
rename($outfile,"D:/Test/Original.cxx") or die;
```

This is how I have tried to do it just now.
Any help!

Comment: Which line fails - the `unlink` or the `rename`?  What is the `die` error message?

Comment: It dies at rename. It says "Permission denied".

Comment: One of the files in question is open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try testing the output of your commands. The [unlink](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html) command returns the number of files deleted. You can use this information to test whether the file was deleted or not:

```
 unlink $file or die qq(Cannot delete file "$file"\n;
 rename $outfile, $file or die qq(Cannot rename file "$outfile" to "$file\n);
```

This will give you an idea whether the `unlink` is failing or the `rename`. There's a possibility that the file is still open. If you're adding lines to the file, make sure you use `close` to close the file handle first:

```
open my $in_fh, "<", $file or die qq(Cannot open "$file" for reading\n);
open my $out_fh, ">", $outfile or die qq(Cannot open file "$outfile" for writing\n)

...   #What ever you're doing

close $in_fh;     #Close your files, so nothing is holding them open.
close $out_fh;
unlink $file or qq(Cannot delete file "$file"\n);
rename $outfile, $file or qq(Cannot rename "$outfile" to "$file"\n);
```

On Windows, it is especially important to close all file handles before doing anything. Even a *read* will prevent you from doing anything to the files.

Comment: I have closed the file handles. And now the delete is happening. BUt while renaming my data is lost completely. Any idea why that might be the case

Comment: Do you get an error message when attempting to rename? Use the `File::Copy` module (put `use File::Copy;` in your program near the other `use` statements, and use `copy $outfile, $file;`. This way, if the copy fails at least you don't lose your data.

Comment: No. I don't get any error messages while renaming. In fact the return code is also `1`. So I did this thing. I first copied data from `$outfile` to `$file`. And then `unlink $outfile`. This worked!

Answer (score 1):

If this still doesn't work you should get a good clue why

```
unlink($file) && rename($outfile,$file) or die "$! $file";
```